# € sign in method name fails test case using Gradle

Tags: android, testing, gradle, gradlew

I am using windows 8 as operating system.
I have a test method in Robolectric which has € in method name. When I run the test using Gradle wrapper in Android studio with `gradlew test` command, 
it is showing me following error:

```
error: illegal character: \172
    public void change_Ôé¼10() {
                                                           ^
2 errors                                     
:client:compileTestDebugJava FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':client:compileTestDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Try:        
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug

BUILD FAILED
```

I have researched about it and found out it could be related to encoding to UTF-8 
It seems I need to use it without BOM:

[Illegal Character when trying to compile java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992933/illegal-character-when-trying-to-compile-java-code)

[Android Project Compiled with Ant doesn't compile, Illegal Character Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200299/android-project-compiled-with-ant-doesnt-compile-illegal-character-error)

But I do not know how to fix it in a proper way exactly. Do you have any suggestion to fix in Android studio terminal?

Addenda: A friend of mine who uses Linux has no problem to run the test.

Comment: What about not using "exotic" characters in class or method names? It's not a good idea anyway...

Comment: Use E instead? or Euro? why do you need such a characteR?

Comment: I can't even find those characters on my keyboard. Great job...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to fix this would be to remove the character from the method name.

I dont know of any actual limitations - you mentioned it works on a Linux machine - but it is terrible practice. Just spell out the word

> Euro

Comment: Indeed. Best fix in town. Just don't use such characters.