# Cannot compile Java file with non-ASCII character

Tags: java, encoding, compiler-errors, notepad, byte-order-mark

**Important:**

*I must use plain windows notepad only (neither IDE nor Notepad++ or any other text editors allowed).*

So I have a simple class:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       char c = 'қ';
       System.out.println(c);
    }
 }
```

By default notepad saves text files using ANSII encoding, but as you can see I have a non-ANSII character in my code. I can compile and run this code via command prompt, but output is `?` instead of `қ`, which seems obvious. When I change the file's encoding to UTF-8, compiler throws an error. I have read this article [Illegal Character when trying to compile java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992933/illegal-character-when-trying-to-compile-java-code) but there is no solution for my particular problem, because as I wrote above, I am not allowed to use any text editors but Windows notepad.

Thank you!

Comment: I copied the same code. When I ran through visual studio code, same o/p as mentioned. But unable to compile through cmd getting following error:           a.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u00bb'
∩╗┐class Test{
 ^
a.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u00bf'
∩╗┐class Test{
  ^
a.java:3: error: unclosed character literal
       char c = '╥¢';
                ^
a.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u203a'
       char c = '╥¢';
                  ^
a.java:3: error: unclosed character literal
       char c = '╥¢';
                   ^
5 errors

Comment: You can not do it using Windows Notepad.

Comment: @SumanDey As I understood the reason is a character called BOM that Windows appends at the beginning of a file to signal that this file is using a non-ASCII encoding. But how to fix this?

Comment: How are you telling javac which character encoding your source file uses?

Comment: @TomBlodget I am not telling javac anything. If you mean whether or not am writing "javac -encoding UTF8 Test.java", yes I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Every human and program must be told which character encoding a text file uses; though some are willing to guess, if that's what you want.

Comment: @TomBlodget No, actually I was just wondering why it is not working. Obviously, I will not use notepad while writing a real code. Also, I could not even type this character manually in cmd, so probably windows cmd does not support it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need like this:

```
char c = '\u039A';
```

I don't know the code of your 'k', but you may find it on https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html

Also hopes that Windows has this character for output in the console

p.s. The console of windows has a certain code page. Try to change it in console, for example:

```
REM change CHCP to UTF-8
CHCP 65001
CLS
```

and remember about different fonts in windows console, some of them can't draw specific symbols.

Comment: Seems like Windows has not this character in its "available character pool" or whatever, because I cannot even type it manually. It is really weird...

Comment: Ok, you may use '@ECHO OFF
REM change CHCP to UTF-8
CHCP 65001
CLS'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is that javac is non-compliant in not accepting the BOM with UTF-8.

Use Notepad to save as Unicode (actually UTF-16LE).

Compile with

```
javac -encoding UTF-16 Test.java
```

Comment: What is it failing to comply with?  Does the Unicode specification require text processors to intuit encoding from an initial BOM?

Comment: No, it requires them to accept a BOM except when explicitly given an encoding that has a byte ordering and that is given too. (Would have been much simpler if they would have prohibited it when the encoding does not have a byte order. )

Comment: It appears that when given an encoding that has a byte ordering (other than UTF-8), a BOM is forbidden.  From https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom9: “…if a text data stream is marked as UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE or UTF-32LE, a BOM is neither necessary nor *permitted.*” (emphasis theirs)  I agree with your command line solution, though.

Comment: It compiled, but output is still `?` instead of `қ`

Comment: @MukhamedaliZhadigerov Are you sure the `қ` character can be displayed in the command window?

Comment: @VGR No, I am not. How to check it?

Comment: @MukhamedaliZhadigerov Try to paste the character into the command window directly.

Comment: @VGR Interesting... I cannot even type it in the cmd. Why is that? Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197177/discussion-between-mukhamedali-zhadigerov-and-vgr).